# Is this an attempt to disguise someone's edits as ones own?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48276045/903011) and got a [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48279131/903011) which expanded someone's else comment below my question. Since the comment was not turned into an answer this is fine by me.

I [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48279131/revisions) the answer to add some formatting, links to documentation, etc. and they were automatically accepted.

Reviewing how my question is going, I noticed what I thought being a change in the UI, namely the fact that the last editor is not present anymore. I do not care about this visibility but this triggered me to have a look at the revisions.

I was a bit surprised to see

- the initial answer
- my modifications
- a rollback to the original answer by the author
- an edit by the author replying my exact edit

**I do not assume any kind of malice so I was wondering what such an activity can be?**

Comment: Might have been a misclick followed by a correction. We can only speculate.

Comment: I pinged the answerer/editor, he might chime in.

Comment: If you're making code changes to someone else's post (which one should not do too lightly), it's usually best to explain the reason for it in the edit summary (even if it's just something simple, like e.g. "removed the assignment, which isn't necessary in this case"). I can certainly imagine someone rolling back what they think might be a change that breaks the code (and then possibly later realising that the change is actually better).

Comment: Do you care who the edits are attributed to? Does it matter? As long as the answer is of the best quality and content, then the name on the edit is irrelevant..

Comment: @DavidG That it doesn't matter is all the more reason to be confused as to why someone would bother changing the name on an edit. It's not surprising that someone would ask about an action that seems to have no reasoning behind it.

Comment: Actually, the "second edit by the author" is also a rollback, to your original revision. Probably just an "oops" moment. **It may be worth debating, however, whether rollback edits should cause the "last editor" to be the author of the rollbacked-to revision, instead of whoever made the rollback.**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> an edit by the author replying my exact edit

No, that's not what happened. See the "Rollback to Revision 2"? That means that instead of reapply your edit, as you thought, the OP simply reverted to your edit of the answer, by rolling back the rollback.

The fact that the site presents this as last edited by the OP is a little bit misleading, but that's not the fault at all of the OP there. I don't see any attempt to misrepresent your edit.

Answer (score 21):

Usually, this is the result of someone rolling back an edit, then having second thoughts or realizing that perhaps that edit was fine after all, and undoing their rollback.

If they start to do this repeatedly, they may be trying to bump their post or something. That's when, perhaps, a flag is warranted.